# sed, replace on a matched group

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to replace a character on a matched group only

Input:

```
Foo("test-me");
```

Looking for the following output:

```
Foo(TEST_ME);
```

The below command catch the text between quotes and set it uppercase

```
sed 's/Foo("\([^"]*\)");/Foo(\U\1);/'
```

=>

```
Foo(TEST-ME);
```

Just missing the

```
s/-/_/g
```

Comment: So should the output have the quotes (`Foo("TEST-ME")`) or no?

Comment: Try `sed 's/Foo("\([^"-]*\)-\([^"-]*\)");/Foo(\U\1_\2);/' `. Or can there be multiple `-`s?

Comment: no quote on the output

Comment: only works if there is only one "-"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a conditional loop to replace any number of hyphens between the parenthesis:

```
sed 's/Foo("\([^"]*\)");/Foo(\U\1);/;:a;s/\(Foo([^)-]*\)-/\1_/;ta;'
```

details:

```
:a;  # define the label "a"
s/\(Foo([^)-]*\)-/\1_/; # replace the first hyphen
ta;  # if something is replaced, go to label "a"
```